# Equivalent of reading Python files in bytes 'rb' in MATLAB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, file

I read some files in `Python` as follows:

```
with open("C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\testPicture.jpg", 'rb') as FID:
    fileInBytes = FID.read()
```

This returns a bytes string in `Python`.

Running `type(fileInBytes)` returns `<class 'bytes'>`.

I need to call a `Python` function from `MATLAB`. The `Python` function expects the file instance as a bytes string, as described above. So, I would need to do the following in `MATLAB`:

- Read in file from `MATLAB` in format, which will map, when calling a `Python` function from `MATLAB`, as a bytes string.

From this [document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-python.html), I believe, `uint8` in `MATLAB` converts to `bytes` in `Python`.

How can I achieve this? I'm guessing I just need to read a file in `uint8` format in `MATLAB` and pass that into `Python`

Comment: Have you tried your own suggestion?

Comment: I haven't been able to find reading uint8 in Matlab from a file

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`fopen` manual page](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), files are opened in binary mode unless `t` is in the permission string.

According to [`fread` manual page](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html), precision, there is reading into `uint8`:

`fread(fid, '*uint8');`

Presto.

Comment: This should work: data = fread(fid, '*uint8');

Comment: @AliÖzgürArgunşah Edited.